# SoftLayer Virtual Guest host Status list

Tags: java, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I create a Virtual Guest, I need to know the Virtual Guest about Running, Active, and provision scripts execution result.

As we know for the Hardware there have below status for the host provisioning:

```
* '''ACTIVE''': This server is active and in use.
* '''DEPLOY''': Used during server provisioning.
* '''DEPLOY2''': Used during server provisioning.
* '''MACWAIT''': Used during server provisioning.
* '''RECLAIM''': This server has been reclaimed by SoftLayer and is awaiting de-provisioning.
* 
* Status from SoftLayer Host Power State:
* '''Halted''': This Virtual Server Power State is Power off
* '''Running''': This Virtual Server Power State is Power on
```

So I want to know the full status list for Virtual Guest Object, and full list of SoftLayer Host Power State.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status for VMs are:

> Status for SoftLayer Virtual Guest State:
>
> - '''ACTIVE''':                            The virtual guest is active and in use.
> - '''DISABLED''':                       The virtual guest is disabled.
> - '''INACTIVE''':                        The virtual guest is inactive.
> - '''DELETED''':                         The virtual guest has been reclaimed.
> - '''ACTIVE UTILITY''':           This is for Net Scalers.
> - '''DISCONNECTED''':            This is used when the network interfaces were disconnected for security reasons.
> - '''RESOURCE RESERVE''':   This is used when an order has been placed, an instance is reserved, after that, it’s removed.
>
> Status for SoftLayer Virtual Guest Power State:

> - '''Halted''':    This virtual guest power state is Powered off
> - '''Running''': This virtual guest power state is Powered on
> - '''Paused''': This virtual guest has been paused
> - '''Suspended''': This status is set before the VSI is deleted
> - '''Unknown''':

regarding to know the result of the provisioning scripts, currenlty there is no status for that, the only way is loggin into the machine and see if the script ran for more information please see this https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/jarteche/getting-started-user-data-and-post-provisioning-scripts

Also as you can see the VSIs do not have status when this is deploy proccess, in case you want to know this I recomend you to take a look the transaction. When a deploy or reload or upgrade proccess is running a transaction is created and you can see the related transaction by calling this method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getActiveTransaction

if the result is different from empty that means that a transaction is running, the transaction itself contains more information about the proccess that is running

I hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks very much! it's very helpful for me.