# common set of values for SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Power_State

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

From below link , I can only know that the power state class provides a common set of values for which a guest's power state will be presented in the SoftLayer API.

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Power_State

But who can tell me what is the full set of this value?
poweroff/poweron/disconnect? or other discription? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look the answer in this forum:

[SoftLayer Virtual Guest host Status list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139441/softlayer-virtual-guest-host-status-list)