# SoftLayer Curl Command Does Not Match UI Output

Tags: api, curl, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I've been creating and deleting VMs, and trying to pull their status throughout the processing of the order.
The output is always **'{"id":[ID],"statusId":1001}'** no matter where in the process the order is.

In the UI, it may say 'Attaching Primary Disk', but it will always output 'Active' and '1001' using the API.

The command used:

```
curl https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/Softlayer_Hardware_Server/[serverID].json
```

Is there a reason why this doesn't work? Is there a solution to getting the status using the API?

Comment: I'm a little confused, when you say "deleting VMs", are talking about virtual guest?, because the service you are using is for hardware servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the status you see in UI **"Attaching Primary Disk"**, I think you are talking about the transaction status, to retrieve that information you can use the following methods

For Virtual Guests:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getActiveTransaction
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getActiveTransactions
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getLastTransaction

For Hardware Servers:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getActiveTransaction
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getActiveTransactions
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getLastTransaction

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new VM the status will be ¨Active¨ and statusId= 1001 , it means it is in use, when you cancel a VM the status will be ¨Disconnected¨ and statusId= 1006 before to be canceled completely.

After that the status is ¨RESOURCE RESERVE¨ before removing the VM, in this status the VM is not longer listed for users whether through the api o UI.

For more reference you can see the following link:
[SoftLayer Virtual Guest host Status list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139441/softlayer-virtual-guest-host-status-list)

Try with below curl command to retrieve the VM status:

```
curl -k "https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[vmId]/getObject.json" | python -mjson.tool
```

Or you can use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[vmId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[status]
```